# "ImportError: cannot import name TCPLogstashHandler" when trying to push python logs to logstash

Tags: python, logstash

I'm trying to push python logs to logstash but I keep hitting the above mentioned error. My pip file has python-logstash listed and it gets installed. I am then running into an error "ImportError: cannot import name TCPLogstashHandler" when i execute the following code.

```
import logging
import logstash
from logstash import TCPLogstashHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('logme')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = TCPLogstashHandler("localhost", 5044, version=1)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I've tried setting it in a logging configuration file as well but no use. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I use python2.7 and python-logstash@0.4.6

Comment: Did you name your script `logstash.py`?

Comment: i wish it was that simple, but unfortunately that's not the case @KlausD.

Comment: Then open a Python inactive interpreter from the same working folder, run `import logstash; logstash` and see what file gets imported.

Comment: @KlausD I had renamed my file after originally naming it logstash.py but the pyc file still existed and was being referenced.  Things work after i cleaned up my *.pyc files. Thanks for the tip. Feel free to submit an answer?